# How to implement async file download in C# ActiveX

Tags: c#, c++, activex

I'm doing a reimplementation of a C++ ActiveX control in C#.

The C++ Version uses a property class which inherits from CDataPathProperty. How should the following code look in C#?

```
class CFileProperty : public CDataPathProperty
{
 DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CFileProperty )
    ...
}
```

Any references appreciated.

What I'm actually trying to do is: The ActiveX is hosted in IE, inside an object tag:

```
<object type="application/content-type" data="path-or-url-to-file">
    <PARAM name="Url" value="path-or-url-to-file" />
</object>
```

So IE should download the file itself and provide it to the ActiveX. I must ensure that the file is not downloaded twice! Of course I would appreciate a solution, where the data parameter is used and the url parameter is obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a CDataPathProperty conterpart in C#. So I was looking for an alternative approach.

In order to handle the object tag with content type and data attributes correctly one can implement IPersitMoniker. The only relevant method is Load.

```
 public void Load(int fFullyAvailable, IMoniker pmk, IBindCtx pbc, uint grfMode)
 {
     if (pmk == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("pmk");

     string url;
     pmk.GetDisplayName(null, null, out url);

     // Use the moniker to download the persisted data
     // and obtain an IStream on that data
     Guid iid = InterfaceID.IID_IStream;
     object pStream;
     pmk.BindToStorage(pbc, null, ref iid, out pStream);

     // do whatever you want with the data inside pStream
     ...
}
```